# Where is my .Net assembly located on hard disk?

Tags: .net

When I create a Console Application that prints out "Hello World" it is saved in Visual Studio/Projects/*Name of solution*.
But where **EXACTLY** are **assembly**/**assemblies**(is there more than one?) for this application **located?**

There are multiple files and folders in solution so please be precise.

Comment: Are you asking where the dlls reside?

Comment: Dlls are located in /bin folder

Comment: There are two **XML configuration files**, one **PDB file**, two **Application files** and one **Manifest file** in /bin folder. I don't see .dll files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two pieces of information, both located in your project properties. To open the properties right click on the project (not the solution) and go to properties.

On the "Application" tab you will see a box labeled "Assembly Name" (Blue box) and a drop-down labeled "Output Type" (Red box)

[image]

The assembly name determines the file-name and the output type determines the extension. Output types "Console Application" and "Windows Application" will produce a `.exe` file, a output type of "Class Library" will produce a `.dll`. So for the above image the file would be named `ConsoleApplication2.exe` because it is a console application output type.

The location of that file can be found on the "Build" tab

[image]

The "Output path" is the location the file will be located at as a relative position of the project. So my file would be located at `Visual Studio/Projects/Name of solution/ConsoleApplication2/bin/Debug/ConsoleApplication2.exe`, you will find other files in that folder, you don't need them for basic applications but if your application uses a `app.config` file you will need to copy the `ConsoleApplication2.exe.config` file and if you use other dll's as references in your project those do need to be copied to the final location too. You do not need to copy any of the `ConsoleApplication2.vshost` files, nor files that end in `.pdb` or `.xml`.

Comment: Thanks Scott. But I don't see the whole puzzle yet, bear with me for two more questions.
My solution is consisted of only one **.exe** assembly? 

And that assemblies manifest is referencing these [namespaces](http://snag.gy/4hlKW.jpg) from **mscorlib.dll** but **mscorlib.dll** is not physically in my solution folder but rather in **GAC**?

Comment: 1) Your solution ([red line](http://i.stack.imgur.com/liB7x.png)) consists of one or more projects ([blue line](http://i.stack.imgur.com/liB7x.png)) each project will produce a single `.exe` or a single `.dll`. 2) if a file is in the GAC you do not need a copy of the file to be in the same folder as the program. All of the files you have listed in that screenshot are in the GAC. If your program needs the dll to be there it would have automaticly been copied to the `bin/debug` or `bin/release` folder.